# Increase Badge Count From Client side not from Payload Receive count

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, push-notification

I am working on application that receives notification and set application badge.
 The problem is that when the application is in background state or terminated, the badge count isn't increased.
It remains same.

While when app is in foreground method calls and badge count increased.
I already did that thing from server side, 
but I want to know that **Is there any method that execute when app is in background or terminated for increasing application badge number?**

I already told you I have done this thing as

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9
    }
}
```

from server side but what I want is :**I dont want to receive that badge count from server payload but I want to increase badge count from my side.**
 
**My logic is like that when I receive first notification I saved count in userdeafualts in didReceiveNotification and when I second notification I added count with +1 and when app is in foreground I directly change that badge count as 0 in userdefaults BUT THIS METHOD CANT WORK IN BACKGROUND OR APP TERMINATED**

**SO I WANT TO KNOW IF THERE IS ANY METHOD THAT EXECUTES IN BACKGROUND OR APP IS TERMINATED SO I CAN INCREASE BADGE COUNT**

If anyone knows please help me do it from my side.

Comment: This article could be helpful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14256852/3426053

Comment: It seems that i have to do calculations on server side and receive a count from payload and set as application badge number.

but my problem i dont want count from server side.

I already mention that this thing is done from server side

Comment: The best you can do is set `content-available: 1` in the `aps` dictionary and pray.  There is no guaranteed way to trigger background execution (whether the app is running or not), except for Push Kit, which is confined to VoIP apps.

Comment: What i do when application receives notification, I save the count in user defaults and when application receives another notification i just add that count by 1.

Now when application enters background or terminated that method didnt call and my count is remain same

Comment: I want just simple method that just execute in background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update badge with push notification while app in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background)

Comment: Ohh sorry read question carefully. I already write that I did it from server side I want to do it from client side

Comment: @Mark Now check my question and remove that duplicate mark. I think this question is worth in bounty questions

Answer (score 2):

Use `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` of `UIApplicationDelegate`. System wakes up your app, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode. For more info check the documentation for this method

Answer (score 2):

To receive a push notification when your app is in the background you need to update the Capabilities of your Target in Xcode and add Background Modes...Remote Notifications. You must then add the key `content-available` to the payload and set to 1. This will trigger `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`. See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

When the app is terminated there is nothing you can do.

Comment: can `voip` be handy even app terminates?

Comment: Perhaps. But not sure if apple would approve PushKit use for a non-voip app and it's a ton of overhead with certificates etc.

Comment: This seems to be right! You need to turn on `remote notification` from `background modes` under `capabilities`!!

Answer (score 1):

If you will check in AppDelegate.m file, there is a method you can use to let know whether the app is in the background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this method only called once when application enter background. I want a method which calls everytime when I receives notification.

Comment: you can make use of remote notification feature in IOS,Check this link this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719528/how-to-handle-ios-remote-notification-while-app-is-in-background

Comment: I already told you that i already did this thing from server side. I want to update my badge count from my side. So when i receive notification single method calls in background and update my badge count which is store in userDefault.


There is no issue when app is in foreground